# Two branches connect without vpn appliance

Tags: vpn, site-to-site-vpn

i have one issue to connect a two location in different city together to transfer a file and RDP all machine use WIN 7 OS , i have one idea to install two appliance VPN but on this case there is any solution to connect between these branche without using any VPN appliance ??

Note: in all location i use 4 pc's almost.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a central VPN server running in a cloud service such as Amazon or Google, there are also paid VPN services.

Your systems would then connect to the VPN server and would all be on the same network.

One example of this is the OpenVPN access server in Amazon AWS, which is a very simple setup.

More details can be found here: https://openvpn.net/index.php/access-server/cloudmachines/64-access-server-paid/general/513-access-server-amazon-vpc.html